# Is there going to be a film version of "Temeraire"?

Tags: adaptations, temeraire

I think I remember reading that Peter Jackson had bought the rights of *Temeraire* by Naomi Novik and was considering doing a TV show or animated. Seen a few fake YouTube clips but can't find anything via Google or IMDb.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2006/10/11/books/11novi.html - Not recent

Comment: Yeh that was the article but think there a 6 books now and that was 12 years ago. Has Jackson lost his appetite after the Hobbit?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/comicyears.com/books/naomi-novik-deadly-education-adaptation/amp/

Comment: Films based on books? That'll never work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fox Studios currently hold the rights to the stories. They were considering an animated version of *His Majesty's Dragon*, but nothing has been forthcoming since this announcement in September 2022.

> FOX continues to bulk up its adult animation roster as it prepares for
> the addition of a two-hour Monday animation block in May 2023,
> announcing that an animated adaptation of Naomi Novik’s Temeraire
> fantasy novels, dubbed His Majesty’s Dragon, is in development with a
> script commitment.
>
> <sub><sup>[FOX Developing Animated Fantasy Drama ‘His Majesty’s Dragon’](https://www.animationmagazine.net/2022/09/fox-developing-animated-fantasy-drama-his-majestys-dragon/)</sup></sub>

<s>Although Peter Jackson [optioned the book series](https://www.nytimes.com/2006/10/11/books/11novi.html?_r=0) in 2006 (and was still [discussing what to do with them](https://www.inquisitr.com/3348288/peter-jacksons-next-project-the-temeraire-series/) in 2009) nothing ever came of it. The rights have, as of 2016, now reverted back to the author.</s>

> **So Peter Jackson still has the rights to it then, I'm assuming, otherwise you would have said. Can't even tell us if something is being considered?!**
>
> **Naomi Novik:** *Oh, no, sorry! That option expired a while ago. The rights are mine again, and we're considering many things, but nothing to announce yet.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Reddit AMA: Naomi Novik, author of Uprooted & the Temeraire series](https://www.reddit.com/r/YAwriters/comments/476y90/ama_naomi_novik_author_of_uprooted_the_temeraire/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ta much! Are you familiar with the novels?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Never heard of them. Apparently Uprooted *is* being made into a film.

Comment: Worth noting that movie rights to books are optioned *all the time*, and only a small number of those options are ever used

Comment: was only asking.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Unfortunately,  I can't read

Comment: Last comment was for Arcanist

Comment: @Valorum - *please* use sarcasm responsibly - I read your last comment and nearly choked laughing.

Comment: Maybe I should go hug and kiss some poisonous snakes!!

Comment: @ArcanistLupus - A former colleague of mine turned writer had his book optioned by a movie studio. He was very excited about it until he learned that they'd apparently done so because his title and that of an upcoming film were quite similar.